# Can i use laravel if else condition to check css media query condition and use @include function inside of it

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

i'm currently working on a project and it's really messy one.i want to add a @include function but if only want to add device max with more than 991px.I cannot do it with directly in css because of all content load to one page.so i want to want to check before device with and after that applying that @include function.

eg-

if device width>991px
@include(that content i want to use)
else
nothing happens

so if it's possible to do pls help me guys.for more details here is the my code block

```
<div class=mobilesubcatscontainer>
    @include('search.inc.sidebar.categories.calonmobile')
        <div class="listingtab" id="listingtab">
            <!-- some content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

PLS note that i need to check that include function in code block with somehow...

Thanks!

Comment: You need check window size for responsive design? I mean for  desktop, mobile, tablet ?

Comment: yes i need to apply only that @include function when the device size more than 991px otherwise it won't be apply.

Comment: You can just hide/show the content based on a media query within your general CSS, you don't necessarily need the `@include`, right?

Comment: @geertjanknapen i know it pls read the full question.All things in the website load to same page so cannot use default css to hide it.becasue when hide using default css other content despaired..i want to make a apply css url base.

Comment: @kanchanagodapopla You can check by device type. It can be solution. You can read [this](https://codingdriver.com/laravel-detect-mobile-device-or-desktop.html).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can't detect directly device width with php.

So we need to take help from Javascript. First step, we need to create detect function for when device width change. Then we call our view with get method.

Javascript;

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if(document.documentElement.clientWidth < 991) {
     $.get( "{{route('calonmobile')}}", function( data ) {
      $(".mobilesubcatscontainer").prepend(data);    
     });
  }
});
```

Route.php;

```
Route::get('/calonmobile', function () {
    return view('search.inc.sidebar.categories.calonmobile');
});
```

Comment: Thanks bro i dont know it working or not but i think it's the most suitable answer